# Ruby / cup sorting algorithm wont check if string is an integer

Tags: ruby, algorithm, logic

I have (almost) made a cup sorting algorithm that takes colour and radius parameters then spits out the cups names ranked by the radius length. `Example input`

```
2
blue 7
10 red
```

`Example output`

```
red
blue
```

The problem is that I want to create a filter that checks if the first value is a number when split. Then this number is divided by 2 and both values are reversed. I have tried `is_a? Integer` but get an `expecting end of input` error in the irb console. I tried `== int`.

Here is the code:

```
class Cup
    attr_accessor :colour, :radius

    def initialize(colour, radius)
        @colour = colour
        @radius = radius
    end
end

cups = []

puts "How many cups are there?"
gets.to_i.times do |n| 
  puts "Enter Cup-#{n+1} colour & radius:"
  value = gets.split " "
    if 
        value.first.to_i == int?
    then
        value.first / 2
        value.reverse
        cups << Cup.new(value[0], value[1])
    end 
        cups << Cup.new(value[0], value[1])
end
    print cups.colour.sort_by { |cup| cup.radius }
```

Any other feedback about the algorithm is very much welcomed.

Comment: 1. The result of a call to `to_i` is always **ultimately** integer. 2. To check if the variable `var` is of type `Foo`, one uses `var.is_a?(Foo)` or `case` statement.

Comment: `var.is_a?(Foo)` does not "check if the variable `var` is of type `Foo`, it checks if the *object* that is *referenced* by the variable `var` is an instance of the *module* `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever input is provided by user in console will be string so you can do as below,

```
puts "How many cups are there?"
gets.to_i.times do |n| 
  puts "Enter Cup-#{n+1} colour & radius:"
  value = gets.chomp.split(" ")
  order = Integer(value[0]) rescue false # order will have value if it is proper integer, else false
  cups << (order ? Cup.new(value[1], value[0].to_i) : Cup.new(value[0], value[1].to_i))
end
cups.sort_by { |cup| cup.radius }.each { |cup| puts cup.colour } if cups.present?
```

Use of `to_i` is not valid here, as it will return 0 for string 'red'

And also it is also assumed user is putting integer for sure, otherwise code will not work as it is supposed to.

Comment: Yes. If colour then number it is created as a new cup. If number before colour it is divided and swapped places with the colour then put into the array. This is way different than my approach and will take some time for me to understand. While you're here I refactored the last line to `print cups.sort_by { |cup| cup.radius }` and am given just the Cup id. I'm trying to display the cups by only the colour. Any idea how?

Comment: `cups` is collection of `Cup` objects, so you can sort and display as you want. Can you update your required output in question?

Comment: The required output is exactly the same as it says. Cups display the colour name and from lowest - highest according to radii.

Comment: I corrected small mistake, check whether you have objects in `cups` by using `puts cups.inspect`

Comment: There are Cups in cups with cups.inspect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185213/discussion-between-ray-and-prozak).